# KeyError while using Trainer.predict() with Huggingface

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, keyerror

I have fine-tuned a model for sentiment analysis using BertForSequenceClassification. I'm trying to run a prediction on example sentiment (to find out whether it is negative or positive). Here is my code:

```
model_path = "./path_to_directory_with_config.json"
tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1')
txt = "This was a nice place"
inputs = tokenizer(txt, return_tensors="pt")
print(inputs)
model = transformers.BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_path, num_labels=1)
trainer = Trainer(model)
print(trainer.predict(inputs))
```

This throws an error:

```
KeyError: 'Indexing with integers (to access backend Encoding for a given batch index) is not available when using Python based tokenizers'
```

The model was trained (fine-tuned) with dataset like this:

```
Text                       Sentiment
This was nice place            1
This was bad place             0
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any advise is highly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Software Engineer\Desktop\Projekti\sentiment-analysis\data-raw\bin\inference.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(trainer.predict(inputs))
  File "C:\Users\Software Engineer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 2185, in predict
    output = eval_loop(
  File "C:\Users\Software Engineer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 2275, in evaluation_loop
    for step, inputs in enumerate(dataloader):
  File "C:\Users\Software Engineer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\Software Engineer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 561, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\Users\Software Engineer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 49, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\Users\Software Engineer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 49, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\Users\Software Engineer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 241, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: 'Indexing with integers (to access backend Encoding for a given batch index) is not available when using Python based tokenizers'
```

Comment: what is `Trainer` ? where is it imported/ created ? Also, are you sure about num_labels being `1` and not `2`?

Comment: Which line gives this error?

Comment: Trainer is a built-in class in Huggingface transformers library, it allows us to use Trainer API provided by transformers. As for number of labels, I have only one which is either negative (0) or positive (1). I have no idea what this error message means.

Comment: As the others said, knowing which line threw the error would help a lot. Though I found that you define num_labels=1 -- shouldn't that be 2 as you have two labels (0 and 1)?

Also, there seems to be a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691530/key-error-while-fine-tunning-t5-for-summarization-with-huggingface).

Comment: @Stimmot I have added a full stack trace. About labels, I have understood that multiple labels are used when model is expected to give multiple predictions on same sentiment, which is not the case here. I actually tried to train this model with num_labels=2 but that caused an error (num_labels=1 worked).

Comment: From the stack trace, it seems like the problem is in the data setup, not the model.

Comment: Also, did you check some of the already answered questions about this error? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67691530/key-error-while-fine-tunning-t5-for-summarization-with-huggingface and https://fixexception.com/transformers/indexing-with-integers-to-access-backend-encoding-for-a-given-batch-index-is-not-available-when-using-python-based-tokenizers/

Comment: Problem is solved, I managed to do inferencing without Trainer, using this guide: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-bert-from-the-hugging-face-transformer-library-d373a22b0209